# Airflow does not create user from Dockerfile bash entrypoint

Tags: python, bash, docker, airflow

I don't understand why

```
airflow users create -u admin -p admin -e admin@admin.com -f admin -l admin -r Admin
```

from my `entrypoint.sh` does not create an airflow user.

`entrypoint.sh` is being executed from my Dockerfile

```
....
#execute the bash script
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

The weird thing is that my sqlite, webserver and scheduler are initialized from the same bash file and they do present the expected behavior.

This is my `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# initialize the database
airflow db init

# run the scheduler in the background
airflow scheduler 

# create the user
airflow users create -u admin -p admin -e admin@admin.com -f admin -l admin -r Admin

# run the webserver
exec airflow webserver
```

Since the above does not properly run, now I always have to docker exec into the container and create the user manually, which is undesirable.

Could you please shed some light on what is actually happening & how could I fix this? Thank you !

Comment: Have you checked the logs for errors with the command? Does the webserver need to be started before the user create?

Comment: @jordanm Hello ! Yes, I have - but I keep getting "cannot create user without a role", even though it does have the `-r` flag

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of the file to verify the command are being execute in the way you expect.

Comment: @jordanm I have just run it with the command you provided (both before and after the `#!` command) , and I still get this error `airflow users create command error: the following arguments are required: -r/--role, see help above`. Additionally, I have also tried this  `airflow users create -e "admin@airflow.com" -f "airflow" -l "airflow" -p "airflow" -r "Admin" -u "airflow"`, but to no avail

Comment: The command you added was to add additional debug info the the log.

Comment: @jordanm Ah ! Alright , is just that the log is exactly the same :)

Comment: That's perhaps an indication that it's not executing what you think it is.

Comment: @jordanm Well sir, it does seem like you are correct. When I `echo "Check Check"` from the bash script it doesn't show up in the logs. Do you maybe have any idea whats wrong (whats curious is that the webserver does get initialized)?

Comment: Are you rebuilding (and reuploading if applicable) the docker image between attempts?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I am !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I discovered this very strange behavior. To illustrate, make a dockerfile with only these 2 lines:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3
CMD [ "db" , "init"]
```

then `docker build . -t some-image` and `docker run -it some-image`. You will see that this container successfully runs "airflow db init" upon creation. I guess the base airflow image forces the word "airflow" to append to the front of all commands.

Answer (score 0):

After Some Analysis I have found that

Entry point of docker image was

/usr/bin/dumb-init /entrypoint

After some googling I found

```
FROM apache/airflow
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "/entrypoint airflow db init && /entrypoint airflow webserver" ]
CMD []
```

It worked for me

You can add

```
/entrypoint airflow users create -u admin -p admin -e admin@admin.com -f admin -l admin -r Admin
```